# Why can I ping a web page but not access it through browser?

Tags: c#, networking, proxy, network-programming

I am trying to understand proxy servers, which we have at work. I was wondering, why can I ping a web page but not open it? Surely, pinging needs some interaction between my computer and the web page's servers? Is there a way to retrieve data from a web page through programming? (Not proxy bypassing websites such as V-Tunnel)

Comment: There are many ways to retrieve a page through programming. It seems to me that you are a little confused, your questions seem unrelated. What are you trying to do? Why is this tagged C# if you are asking network questions?

Comment: I was wondering, if some form of communication (the pinging) to a website is possible, if it was possible to get the information of the HTML page using a program (without the use of a outside server).. And while this is mostly a networking question, if someone has an possible example of this, in software form.. C# would simply be my preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ping response has nothing to do with an HTTP Server. When a machine responds a ping request it means that it is accessible through the network. To open a webpage from a certain address, the remote machine must serve that page through an HTTP Server.

In your case, the server machine is on and connected to the network (it responds to `ping`), but the HTTP Server is probably not running/configured.

---

As for the second question, there are many ways to retrieve a web page from code, if you google you will find many examples. In C# you could use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for example:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
```

Keep in mind that this is just like accessing a page using your web browser. If you have a proxy in your network, any request to the Internet goes through it.

Comment: Thanks nmat, that clears up some things.. I was under the impression that network communication, be it HTML or pinging was all the same.

I then assume that proxies only cover some ports?

Comment: @Corne No, different protocols generally use different ports. A proxy server usually sits between your machine and the Internet. You connect to the server on a specific port (8080 or 3128), it forwards the request to the internet and sends the response back at you. The proxy server doesn't need (and probably doesn't have) an HTTP Server running

Comment: @Corne I've updated the anwser. Note that being able to ping a server has nothing to do with being able to access a page on that server. Like I side, it might not even have a page, or that access might be blocked to you by the proxy

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I Learned something new..

Answer (score 0):

> Why can I ping a web page

You can't ping a web page. You can ping a host.

> but not access it through browser?

Because the web page isn't accessible through a browser.

Not a real question.